# Trying to print permutations of a number

Tags: mips32

Question 1

1. We consider the permutation (c d f b e a) as an arrangement of the six
   objects a, b, c, d, e, f in a straight line. Read like: “a becomes c, b
   becomes d, c becomes f, d becomes b, e becomes e, f becomes a.”
2. In cycle notation : (a c f)(b d)
3. The product can be formulated following Fig. 1.
4. In cycle notation: (a c f)(b d) x (a b d)(e f) = (a c e f b).
5. Implement a MIPS code that takes as input a set of permutations in cycle
   notation and computes the product permutation and prints the result in
   cycle notation.
6. Expected Run:
   (a->c b->d c->f d->b e->e f->a)*(a->b b->d c->c d->a e->f f->e)=(a->c b->d c->f d->b e->e f->a)*(c->c d->a f->e b->d e->f a->b)=(a->c b->a c->e d->d e->f f->b) Here -> =becomes.How to solve this problem using algorithm                                                                                                                                                    (a) Enter no of cycles in permutation :
   (b) Enter cycle · · · //in form of an array of ints
   (c) Enter cycle · · ·
   (d) Enter no of cycles in permutation :
   (e) Enter cycle · · · //in form of an array of ints
   (f) Enter cycle · · ·
   (g) Product permutation cycle 1 is :
   (h) Product permutation cycle 2 is :
7. Upload instruction:
   (a) Upload a program with suitable comments
   (b) A report which discusses the algorithm you have designed in detail..

.data
num_cycles_prompt:  .asciiz "Enter no of cycles in permutation:\n"
cycle_prompt:       .asciiz "Enter cycle %d:\n"
product_output:     .asciiz "Product permutation cycle %d is: "
space:              .asciiz " "
newline:            .asciiz "\n"

.text
.globl main

## Function to read an integer from input

read_int:
li $v0, 5       # Read integer syscall code
syscall
jr $ra

## Function to print a string

print_string:
li $v0, 4       # Print string syscall code
syscall
jr $ra

## Main program

main:
# Prompt for the number of cycles in the first permutation
la $a0, num_cycles_prompt
jal print_string
jal read_int
move $t0, $v0   # $t0 = num_cycles1

```
# Read cycles for the first permutation
li $t1, 0       # Cycle counter
```

read_cycles1_loop:
beqz $t0, read_cycles2
la $a0, cycle_prompt
move $a1, $t1   # Pass the cycle number as argument
jal printf_string

```
# Read the elements of the current cycle
# (Store them in cycles1 array)

addi $t1, $t1, 1
sub $t0, $t0, 1
j read_cycles1_loop
```

read_cycles2:
# Similar code to read cycles for the second permutation

```
# Compute product permutation and print results

# End of program
li $v0, 10      # Exit syscall code
syscall
```